# В чём различие между jdk, sdk и j2sdk?

Tags: sdk, java

В чём заключается различие между JDK, SDK и J2SDK?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*SDK (software development kit)* — набор инструментов для разработки приложений для определенной аппаратной/программной платформы.

*JDK (java development kit)* – набор инструментов для разработчика приложений на платформе и языке java (так как для платформы java можно писать приложения и на других языках программирования).

*J2SDK (java 2 software development kit)* – тоже что и JDK но название использовалось для версий 1.2.Х до 1.4.Х. С выходом java версии 1.2 было принято прибавлять цифру 2 к java для указания того что это следующая ступень развития языка/платформы. Добавление 2 продолжалось вплоть до версии java 1.5.0.12. С выходом java  1.5.0.12 двойку убрали.

---

В процессе развития платформы и языка java названия набор инструментов для разработки приложений (SDK) менялось:

- 1.Х использовалось название JDK,
- 1.2.Х по 1.5.11 – J2SDK в вперемешку с JDK,
- 1.5.12 по 1.8.X – JDK.

Более детально историю названия версий можно посмотреть [здесь](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/archive-139210.html).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! То что нужно :)

Comment: @Ksenia, пожалуйста. Спасибо, Вам, за правильные вопросы.

Comment: IBM и сейчас все свои новые версии Java Development Kit до сих пор называет Java SDK (Software Development Kit). Традиция...